# Dynamically Add columns to datagrid in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid

I am trying to make a datagrid, that will dynamically add columns to it based on some condition.
Now, I am able to add the columns, but I want the newly added column to have button using itemRenderer.

I am unable to achieve this though. Getting this error on line 1

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type 1067: Implicit coercion of a
>   value of type mx.controls:Button to an unrelated type
>   mx.core:IFactory. Demo.mxml   /Demo/src   line 14 Flex Problem

Can anyone help ?

Here's a code snippet :

```
private function addDataGridColumn(dataField:String):void {
            var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
            dgc.itemRenderer = button1;    // Line 1 
            var cols:Array = dataGrid.columns;
            cols.push(dgc);
            dataGrid.columns = cols;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration and intialization of button1?

Answer (score 4):

The `itemRenderer` and `itemEditor` properties are of type `IFactory`. When you set these properties in MXML, the MXML compiler automatically casts the property value to the type `ClassFactory`, a class that implements the IFactory interface.

When you set these properties in `ActionScript`, you must explicitly cast the property value to `ClassFactory`

You might be looking for this, adds buttons to all rows of newly added column.

```
private function addDataGridColumn(dataField:String):void {
                var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn();
                dgc.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(Button);
                var cols:Array = dataGrid.columns;
                cols.push(dgc);
                dataGrid.columns = cols;
            }
```

Comment: I was going to post the same answer, so yeah, that's how to do it!